# Java EBNF?

Tags: java, bnf, ebnf

Does anyone know of an accurate source for an (E)BNF for the Java language? Preferably, it would be from an authorative source, e.g. Sun.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[First google result :)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/syntax.doc.html)
Though I can't speak for how up-to-date it might be.

Comment: That's for Java 1.2, so it doesn't have generics, assertions, enhanced for-loops, etc.

Answer (score 5):

i believe the 3rd edition is the latest:

[JLS 3rd edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/syntax.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want the spec for, but you may be interested to know that:

- the parser in Javac is hand written. No parser generated tools.
- there exists a number of repositories for popular parser generators grammars. Here is [JavaCC](https://javacc.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=110&filter=java+1.5) and [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list).

Comment: Both links are dead now.